# Where should a high schooler target getting their paper published?

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals, paper-submission, statistics

[FiveThirtyEight](https://fivethirtyeight.com/) is quite well-regarded in statistics/data analysis circles. I have written a short paper on NBA player ratings that might be of interest to them.

I do intend on getting the paper published somewhere that will help me in the future. My question is this - Should I target getting it published in a small math journal or a platform like FiveThirtyEight ?

I will be going to my sophomore year this fall.

Thanks a ton ;)

Comment: Does 538 even accept external submissions? To be published in a math (or statistics) journal it would probably need some interesting mathematical aspect.

Comment: I don't think this is really on topic here, but good luck with your pursuits.  Go into your local library, and ask at the reference desk for "The Writer's Market" (https://www.amazon.com/Writers-Market-2020-Trusted-Published/dp/1440301220), and ask the reference librarian if they can help show you how to use it to find publishers that might want stuff on your topic.

Comment: @Buffy It does - https://fivethirtyeight.com/how-to-pitch-fivethirtyeight/ . Yes, getting published in a journal would be tough.

Comment: @mukberty, I think you misinterpret that. They are looking for research opportunities, with possible collaboration. I doubt they are looking to publish the work of others. I doubt they would consider it.

Comment: @Buffy I understand now. Sorry for the mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pursue both?

If you think your analysis is statistically new/unique, aim for a journal, although I doubt that as a high-schooler this is realistic, but you can always try. I would suggest to reach out to a university professor to see if they can help you. They should at least be able to assess the quality of what you wrote.

538 is a popular medium, and their articles are aimed at people who like stats but don't necessarily understand them thoroughly. The way that you would write an article for them is **very** different from the way you write a journal article.

What I would suggest anyway: publish it on your own blog/medium/website/github, so you'll also build a portfolio. If you manage to get some attention from 538 your own website will also get some attention.